# is it possible to make the navigate works when using @ with path in visual studio

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Today I found when I write the react path like this:

```
import { requestWithAction } from '@/api/XHRClient'
```

I could not quickly navigate to the XHRClient file using the right click(Ctrl + Click) in Visual Studio. is it possible to let the quick navigate works when using path like '@/api/XHRClient'?